# Jest expect.stringMatching() SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression

Tags: jestjs, string-comparison, ts-jest

We have:
*A function that returns random values (In our case, **crypto** -> **aes**)*

What do we want to do?
*Compare that this string is not equal to the past*

---

*We mean that the object in which the string is located is large enough, so we compare the string inside the object, and not separately*

---

How do we compare?

```js
const oldCiper = "oldRandom+String-/FromAny==Characters";

// Pay attention to the plus sign at the beginning of a new line
const newCiper = "+newRandomString-\From/Any==Charac+ters";

// We will get an error here 
// SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression...
expect({cipher: oldCiper }).toEqual({cipher: expect.not.stringMatching(newCiper)})
```

Full Error:
*SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /+newRandomString-\From/Any==Charac+ters/: Nothing to repeat*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

*Use **stringContaining** instead of **stringMatching***

```js
const oldCiper = "oldRandom+String-/FromAny==Characters";

const newCiper = "+newRandomString-\From/Any==Charac+ters";

expect({cipher: oldCiper }).toEqual({cipher: expect.not.stringContaining(newCiper)})
```

The first character for an error can be not only a plus, but also "W", "L", etc.